# If X is log-normally distributed prove the distribution function in terms of standard normal distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

[image: Problem Question]

I am not being able to solve part C and part D.
Somebody please help!
Thanks

Comment: In the computation of the cumulative distribution function of $X$,, use the subsitution $t=\ln x$.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that $\Phi(0)=1/2$, that answers part (d).  You need
$$
\frac12=\Phi(0)=\Phi\left(\frac{\ln x-\mu}{\sigma}\right),
$$
so
$$
0 = \frac{\ln x-\mu}{\sigma}.
$$
Then remember that a fraction is $0$ only if the numerator is $0$.

Part (c) is really the main thing you should know about the log-normal distribution: $X$ is log-normally distributed iff $\ln X$ is normally distributed.

Two things suffice for part (c): (1) Differentiate both sides of the equality in (c).  On one side you get $f(x)$.  On the other side, recall that $\Phi'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$, and also remember the chain rule.